# what's different in following jquery loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works like expected. It increased the .heads div width when hitting #yy button and decreases it when pressing #zz:

```
var q = ["#zz", "#yy"];
var c;
$.each(q, function(key, value) 
{
    $(document).on('click', value, function() 
    {
        c = (key == 0 ? -20 : 20);
        $('.heads').css("width", $('.heads').width()+c);
    });
});
```

However, when I change the code to the one below, it will in both cases increase the width of the .heads div:

```
var q = ["#zz", "#yy"];
var c;
$.each(q, function(key, value) 
{
    c = (key == 0 ? -20 : 20);
    $(document).on('click', value, function() 
    {
        $('.heads').css("width", $('.heads').width()+c);
    });
});
```

The question is: why? The $.each loop runs twice in both cases and c is -20 in first iteration en +20 in the second. But if I console.log(c) in the .on function it looks like it's +20 in both cases in the last code block and (as expected either -20 or +20 in the first code block.

Comment: Logic issues aside, your loop is completely redundant. Use `$(document).on('click', '#zz, #yy', fn);` and store any related metadata in a `data-*` attribute on the element.

Comment: You mean the `javascript closure`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: They are correct.  It is due to closure.  If you remove var c; on line 2 and update line 5 to be "var c = ....", then it should work again.

Comment: Why even use a loop for this? Why not create two functions, which do different things, or create one function with an if statement inside?

Comment: Bryan Euton is right indeed. But I don't really get the difference. c gets a certain value whether or not it's a global right? in both cases it's used in a valid scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function assigned to `onclick` event is closure. If such functions are created in the loop, they still share the same environment. Your `c` variable is declared outside the `$.each()` loop, that's why in your 2nd example its value is always the same.

Here is the complete explanation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake

Comment: It's not because they share the same loop. You're thinking of when they use a `for` loop. The problem is that `c` is declared *outside* of the correct scope so both handlers share the same `c` value.

Comment: I think that in C language we would say that var c is passed by reference and two different vars c are declared in the change Bryan Euton suggested